# Read only rows with matching data in csv list with python

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm new to python, and trying to understand how to sort data using the csv reader. I've read a couple of guides on this site, but nothing seems to quite relate to what I'm trying.

I have a csv file called buildings.csv, compiled with list data like this:

> ['VANGARDE MONKS CROSS', '1292', 'YO32 9AE', 'GREAT BRITAIN', 'Retail', 'Trading', ''] 
>   ['VILLAGE DOUGLAS CORK SF', '418', 'CORK', 'REPUBLIC OF IRELAND', 'Retail', 'Trading', '']

What I want to know is, how do I return only rows in the list that contain the word 'IRELAND'? At the moment all I'm trying to do is get terminal to read the output from a text file.

Comment: It depends a little bit what you want to do with the data afterwards. I would read the data into a pandas DataFrame and afterwards remove the rows without `IRELAND`. It's also possible to build a dictionary and check while reading in.

Comment: Its a learning exercise for learning python at the moment, before using panda I'd like to know how to do this with standard syntax. Perhaps export the outputted rows into a new CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an easy way if you just want to print the lines:

```
with open('buildings.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if(line.find("IRELAND")!=-1):
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to loop over the rows. Maybe something like this?

```py
l = [['VANGARDE MONKS CROSS', '1292', 'YO32 9AE', 'GREAT BRITAIN', 'Retail', 'Trading', ''], ['VILLAGE DOUGLAS CORK SF', '418', 'CORK', 'REPUBLIC OF IRELAND', 'Retail', 'Trading', '']]
for row in l:
    if any("IRELAND" in s for s in row):
        print "match"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it simple, just filter the rows while reading them from the CSV:

```
with open('buildings.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csv_reader:
        if any("IRELAND" in s for s in row):
            print ', '.join(row)
```

However, generally you will save yourself a lot of time by using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), or a similary library for filtering, sorting, pivoting etc.

Answer (score 0):

Although you said you don't want to use `pandas`, here is a solution, maybe for further reference:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> l = [['VANGARDE MONKS CROSS', '1292', 'YO32 9AE', 'GREAT BRITAIN', 'Retail', 'Trading', ''],
     ['VILLAGE DOUGLAS CORK SF', '418', 'CORK', 'REPUBLIC OF IRELAND', 'Retail', 'Trading', '']]

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(l)  # you can read a file here as well
>>> new_df = df.loc[df[3].apply(lambda x: "IRELAND" in x)]
>>> new_df
                         0    1     2                    3       4        5 6
1  VILLAGE DOUGLAS CORK SF  418  CORK  REPUBLIC OF IRELAND  Retail  Trading
```

`df[3].apply(lambda x: "IRELAND" in x)` acts as a filter: it returns a boolean vector where `True` indicates that `IRELAND` is in a row at column 3. `df.loc[]` returns the dataframe where the argument is true.